# Magento - Model override not working

Tags: magento

Please can one of the magento experts out there help me with this.  This has been driving me crazy all day!!!

I am trying to override Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price and anything i try is not working. I have did this sort of things several times before and am confident my code is correct but I am clearly missing something.

The controller is working fine and if I instantiate the model it too works fine.  It appears to be the actual rewrite itself that is not working.

I am using Magento 1.5.1.

Here is the code in my modules config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNs_MyMod>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyNs_MyMod>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <models>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <product_type_price>MyNs_MyMod_Model_Price</product_type_price>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
    </models>
  </global>
    <frontend>
         <routers>
            <mymod>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyNs_MyMod</module>
                    <frontName>mymod</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymod>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Here is the model code stripped back to the bare minimum:

```
    <?php

class MyNs_MyMod_Model_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{
    public function getPrice($product = null) {
        Mage::log('Made it into getPrice()');

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you instantiate a Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_price')?  Do you get an object back?  If so, what's its class?

Comment: Hi Alan.  I get the correct overriden type i.e. MyNs_Mymod_Model_Price.  However, if I add log entries from the core model Mage_Catalog_Product_Type_Price, these always get logged - the log messages from the overriden class never get logged.

Comment: Providing more context about what pages you're loading and where you're adding the logging you see will help people track down your problem. Magento's new enough and endlessly configurable enough that the quickest way to track down these sorts of issues is to look at the code responsible for instantiating your model, and figuring out why it's not returning what you think it should. The me context you provide, the more people can help.

Comment: Also, a stab in the dark answer provided below

Answer (score 10):

This is a guess here, but based on your comments it sounds like you've successfully rewritten the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` class.  **However**, Magento's rewrite system isn't the "true" duck-typing/monkey-patching you see in Ruby/Python.  The rewrite will only work if the core code is instantiating a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` via the class alias  `catalog/product_type_price`.  It doesn't work with an objet that's an instance of a class that **inherits from** `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`.

So, consider this

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php
<?php
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
```

My guess is the page you're loading instantiates a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price`.  That's why your rewrite appears to be working when you instantiate a `catalog/product_type_price` in isolation, but when the system instantiates a `catalog/product_type_configurable_price` your rewrite doesn't (and can't) be triggered.

Long story short, try rewriting the `catalog/product_type_configurable_price` model instead and see if you have more luck.

If that doesn't work you'll need to track down where the Magento core code is instantiating these objects, and debug what's going on.   Providing more context for your code can help people here help you with that problem.